# Declare a Style TargetType for a NestedClass in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, styles, targettype

I have `MyClass` class.
I declare

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyClass"></Style>
```

no problems.

I have `MyClass.MyNestedClass` (public) class.

I declare ... ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a + to separate the outer class name from the nested class name:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MyClass+MyNestedClass"></Style>
```

Comment: Be aware that this might break your designer surface. There is a known bug concerning this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361509/xaml-designer-cannot-handle-typename-with-nested-classes

Comment: @cplotts the link is dead. Do you happen to know if the bug is still present in most recent Visual Studio version?

Comment: @Crono I don't. My advice would be to simply try it and see if the designer breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant declare nested classes in XAML (afaik), as it interferes with the Xaml parsing logic that assumes the dot notation represents a property

Comment: What you state (i.e. you can't _declare/instantiate_ nested classes) is true ... albeit not what the poster was asking in his question. For those reading this post that want a MSDN reference about how you can't _instantiate_ nested classes in XAML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753379.aspx